# automating selenium 101

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, java, javascript

I'm just getting started with selenium:

```
package selenium;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SeleniumWebPage {

    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SeleniumWebPage.class.getName());
    private final LinkFacade lf = new LinkFacade();

    public SeleniumWebPage() {
    }

    public void processLinks() {
        List<Link> links = lf.getAll();
        for (Link l : links) {
            processLink(l);
        }
    }

    private void processLink(Link l) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  //don't display
        driver.get(l.getLink());
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(9, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        String s = driver.getPageSource();
        log.info(s);
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Apparently it's not really possible, or at least not quite the same, to run a "headless" version of `WebDriver`?

In an event, Does this give all the javascript from the live page?  Optimally, I would like to click links, fill in fields, etc, and then log, as above, any changes to the console.

Is it possible to achieve this with `WebDriver`?

In order to click links, fill in fields and so forth, it's necessary to build some logic to parse the HTML elements?

Comment: http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Do you want just get the HTML and JavaScript code and test them? In this case, you should not use Selenium. Use HTMLUnit, it is a headless web browser and you can also develop your tests in Java.

Comment: For now, I like watching it run. JavaScript,  dynamic content  is what I'm after.  Ajax, content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run headless with either [Headless Chromium](https://github.com/CodeYellowBV/run-headless-chromium)  or with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) ..

Keep in mind that running with Selenium Grid or SauceLabs is equally as good as running headless.

Comment: there's a firefox equivalent?  Or, that would be SeleniumGrid?

Comment: I don't know of a Firefox equivilant except via the service that they call BlazeMeter .  Otherwise, Selenium Grid is the only way.   There is also a way to do detached sessions in Linux using XVFB but its probably really technical.